# MGSplitViewController using Storyboards

Tags: iphone, ios5, uisplitviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I have been working on this for some time now and just cant quite get it to work... Has anyone implemented a MGSplitViewController app using storyboards in iOS 5? I just cant get anything to show up like in the example project and was wondering if there were any tutorials or just steps to getting this to work...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS 5 allows you to custom create **View Controller containers**.
Refer to "[Implementing UIViewController Containment](http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=102)". They have a sample project demo, but not sure if they have published the source code.

I think you can create a root ViewController that holds two more child ViewControllers

- Child 1 - Has `UITableView` and is aligned left.
- Child 2 - Has `UIView` for the details on the right.

`MGSplitViewController` style transition could be achieved through    `transitionFromViewController:toViewController:`