# Modal view gets moved to the back when autorotating with MGSplitViewController in iOS 5.x

Tags: ios, ios5, modal-dialog, uisplitviewcontroller, autorotate

I've successfully implemented MGSplitViewController in my application and it seems to work pretty well but in iOS 5.x, it has this weird issue.

1. I start my app with its MGSplitViewController as the root view controller in Portrait.
2. Trigger my full screen modal view controller that gets displayed over top successfully.
3. Rotate device to Landscape and the view disappears but there's a piece of it still showing through the split view slider.

[image: Modal view showing]

[image: Splitview after rotating]

Has anyone seen this and/or fixed it? It works just fine in iOS 6.

If I rotate the view back or try to open other modal views, nothing happens. It's like that modal view is stuck behind.

Note: This is how I setup my MGSplitViewController: [Known effort to update MGSplitViewController for iOS5 and Storyboards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10704609/known-effort-to-update-mgsplitviewcontroller-for-ios5-and-storyboards/14348245#14348245)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok well I figured out what the problem was.

I was presenting my modal views (and segues) from the tab Controller or the detail view controller and the modal views (and global modal segues) needed to be presented from the MGSplitViewController instead.

When I was using UISplitviewController, I had been able to present the modal views/segues from that controller but when I switched to MGSplitViewController, it was not represented in the storyboard so I tried setting global modal segues (such as login) to the tab bar controller which is the master controller. This seemed to cause the issue.

For modal views, I ended up presenting them from the MGSplitViewController and I had to remove the segue I had and simply present any modal view controllers I had previously segued directly from the MGSplitViewController instead.